# Fragile wires soldered to a card edge socket in a 50-year old camera keep on breaking

Tags: pcb, connector

I'm working on an old camera from the 70s, a Pentax ES. It has a PCB with ~20 in/outputs through a 2x10 PCB connector. The wires are soldered to the connector and they're very brittle. Each time when I succeed soldering one on, another one comes loose (they usually just break off when manipulating the connector). Problem is that I have to trim a wire a couple of mm before resoldering and since this seems to become a never ending story, the wires will become too short and there's no way to replace them by a new wire than by disassembling the whole camera :(

So I'm looking for a better solution to attach the wires to the connector, or replace the connector by something else all together.

I was thinking of using these crimp pins that I have  for making my own connectors from a Raspberry Pi project (see picture).

But perhaps there are other solutions that would involve no or simple soldering.

Main constraint is size (it has to fit in the camera!). Robustness is no big constraint, because it'll be protected in the camera housing, no stress applied.

[image: PCB with connector (two-sided, 2x10)]

[image: wires soldered to the connector]

[image: crimp leads that could fit the connector]

Comment: I wonder what's the motivation for doing this seemingly frustrating work?

Comment: Well, getting the camera operational is my motivation. But if yout want, you can blame me for stubborness :)

Comment: The solder they used in the 1970s would have most likely been the eutectic Sn63/Pb37 alloy… the modern lead-free solders seem to be more brittle in my opinion

Comment: How are you stripping the wire?  Are you nicking or severing strands?

Comment: For one-off test fixtures, I like to get the wiring all situated then encase in hard hot-melt glue (not the rubbery stuff.)  Makes a good 'solder strain relief' but obviously this hinders rework-ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crimp pins are loo long and will not fit in the camera. Other than that, you do have the right idea. Crimp each wire to a [ferrule](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/terminal-block-wire-ferrules/364) or [wire pin](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/terminals/wire-pin-connectors/397), then solder its tip into a solder cup. I would try [10 mm insulated ferrules](https://www.digikey.com/short/0j7tvtnn).

[image: Ferrules]

{My picture}

Comment: Hi, I finally gathered my courage to finish the project. I took the smallest size that I could find (awg26) and even those I had to cut in half. I gave up soldering, but the ferulles sit snug when I push them in the connector clamps. Contact seems and it's all protected inside the camera body, so let's hope they stay fixed. Thanks again for pointing the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You need some strain relief on the wires. The solder is probably creeping along the wire and making it solid so that when flexed it breaks.

Try de-soldering the wires, slip on the smallest heatshrink that will go over the pins, solder up and shrink.